# "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x91 in position 23: invalid start byte" error while using Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to create automatic number plate recognition system and I wanted to use tensorflow object detection api in google colab. I am getting this error

This is the link containing the full error https://ibb.co/mzH7NgQ

Comment: https://ibb.co/mzH7NgQ

Comment: Can you post your `xxxx_label_map.pbtxt` file. The error was likely caused by the wrong format in the  lable map file.

Comment: item {
 id: 1
 name: ‘plate’
}